AVCaptureVideoDataOutput flashes old data?
I have a setup along the lines below, and it works well, except for one thing: every time I start the camera, the view seems to briefly show the last frame from the last time the camera was active. Is there a way to clear the buffer or similar, without tearing down the setup completely?
private let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
let captureSessionQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.example.apple-samplecode.CaptureSessionQueue")
var captureDevice: AVCaptureDevice?
var videoDataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()

...

guard let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .back) else { return }
self.captureDevice = captureDevice
captureSession.sessionPreset = .hd1920x1080

guard let deviceInput = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice) else { return }
if captureSession.canAddInput(deviceInput) {
    captureSession.addInput(deviceInput)
}

videoDataOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true
videoDataOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: videoDataOutputQueue)
videoDataOutput.videoSettings = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange]
if captureSession.canAddOutput(videoDataOutput) {
    captureSession.addOutput(videoDataOutput)
    videoDataOutput.connection(with: .video)?.preferredVideoStabilizationMode = .off
} else {
    return
}

